# How to append input elements dynamically in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to append new input fields based on a condition, I will describe the workflow to help you understand

First stage is to press this button to implement 2 functions(1 is to move to other fieldset in the staged form, second function is to append the inputs:

```
<input type="button" name="secondBtn" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="secondBtn" @click="nextPlusappend"/>
```

nextPlusappend:

```
nextPlusappend() {
    this.isNextClicked();
    this.appendFields();
}
```

appendFields:

```
    //this.platform initllized as 'one' so the condition is true.


 if(this.platform === 'one'){
        this.inputFields.push({
            Username: '',
            Password: '',
            AffiliateID: '',
            CI: '',
            GI: '',
        })
    }
```

And I want to append all the fields from the function to this fieldset:

```
<div v-if="currentPage === 2">
  <fieldset id="fieldset3"  v-for="(param, index) in inputFields" :key="index">
    <h2 class="fs-title">API Credentials</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3- Add any parameter for the integration</h3>

    <input v-model="param.Username" type="text" name="`inputFields[${index}[Username]]`" placeholder="userName">
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" @click="isPreviousClicked"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Create a Ticket" id="excel"/>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
```

How can I append this without hard code all the input fields as I did here:?

```
<input v-model="param.Username" type="text" name="`inputFields[${index}[Username]]`" placeholder="userName">
```

This is designated to be dynamic, what do i mean?
I mean that if the this.platform is equal to "one"  there will be a unique fields, and if this.platform equal to "two" for example there will be other unique fields.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think like "pushing a form field", rather think like "adding a new item to the dataset" (and of course, its displayed UI is a form field).

Let me give an example:

```js
Vue.component("FormField", {
  props: ["label", "value"],
  computed: {
    val: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("update:value", val)
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickAdd() {
      this.$emit("click-add-field")
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>
        {{ label }}: <input type="text" v-model="val" />
      </label>
      <button
        @click="handleClickAdd"
      >
        + ADD
      </button>
    </div>
  `,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      formFields: [{
        label: "Field 1",
        value: null,
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickAddField() {
      const item = {
        label: `Field ${ this.formFields.length + 1 }`,
        value: null,
      }
      this.formFields = [...this.formFields, item]
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div
      class="container"
    >
      <div
        class="col"
      >
        <h4>FIELDS:</h4>
        <hr>
        <form-field
          v-for="(field, i) in formFields"
          :key="i"
          :label="field.label"
          :value.sync="field.value"
          @click-add-field="handleClickAddField"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        class="col"
      >
        <h4>FIELD VALUES:</h4>
        <hr>
        <div
          v-for="(field, i) in formFields"
          :key="i"
        >{{ field.label }}: {{ field.value }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see, that on `ADD` I just added a new item in the `formFields` - the values are bound in the template to a child-component, that handles the actual representation of the fields.

On the right side of the snippet, you can see another benefit of decoupling data from UI: I created another representation of the same data source - that immediately reacts to any changes!

Comment: This showed me the right way to do it. Thank you!